# Unexpected behaviour with CSS Keyframe animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to have an element scale up from 0 on page load, but that element needs to be rotated. Seems like a simple thing, but it seems to apply the rotation after the animation finishes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes scale{
    0%{-webkit-transform: scale(0);}
    100%{-webkit-transform: scale(1);}
}
div{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-animation: scale 2s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mildfuzz/wnpVp/

Comment: or opera, no, you're right. Not sure how that helps, though.

Comment: You created fiddle with webkits and now a firefox user has to first edit it

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/wnpVp/3/

Comment: Perfect. Write it as an answer, @Adrift

Comment: in the whole earth didn't you get any other word than scale to name your animation

Comment: What's your point? @Ankit, you seem to either be misunderstanding the problem or being purposely antagonistic.

Comment: Scale is a css property and no need to get aggressive

Comment: @Ankit I am sure you can handle changing some prefixes if you really can't fire up a webkit browser. As a rule, I always dev for webkit prefixes first, and then add support for others later, to keep code readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `transform` shorthand *within* the `@keyframes` rule, as your `rotate()` function is outside the rule and thus not animating like you expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/wnpVp/3